# send Django variable as an AngularJS function parameter

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, angularjs

i want to call an Angular function in html file and parameter of that function is a variable created via Django framework. but i get "undefined" error in my javascript. how i can put Django variable into Angular function call?

this:

```
<div ng-click="getCardInfo(card.name)">
```

card.name is Django variable.

Comment: please provide more of your code

Comment: Please, create a code snippet or plunkr example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django template variables will be evaluated before Angular, so the overlapping {{ }} syntax shouldn't pose a problem. Assuming that card.name is your Django variable (and a string), you should be able to put something like this in your template:

```
<div ng-click="getCardInfo('{{ card.name }}')">
```